# Gronwall inequality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, gronwall-type-inequality

This question concerns a proof of a theorem involving Gronwall type inequality. We have the following:
[image: J. Math. Study doi: 10.4208/jms.v52n1.19.08 Vol. 52, No. 1, pp. 98-110 March 201]

The question is: how did we apply Gronwall type inequality to get estimate (3.6)?

Comment: From $M'(t)+M(t)\leq c(t)$ you get $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}[e^t M(t)]\leq c(t)e^t$ so integrating gives $e^t M(t)-M(0)\leq\int_0^t c(s) e^s\,\mathrm{d}s$, etc.

Comment: So helpful, thanks.